# Get date from coming day and specified date in Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In Carbon, I can do

```
Carbon::parse("This Sunday"); // This gives me coming date for Sunday
```

But I want to get date for day like `get coming date of Sunday after 2018-01-01`. Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: This is exact you are looking for
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this simply with

```
Carbon::parse("2018-01-01")->modify("next Sunday");
```

or using next() which might be faster

```
Carbon::parse("2018-01-01")->next(Carbon::SUNDAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$sunday = Carbon::parse("This Sunday");
$sunday->next(Carbon::SUNDAY);
```

[Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write something like this.

```
Carbon::parse('first sunday of January 2018')
```

The documentation is here http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

*You could possibly do something like:*
As mentioned in the official [documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
$sunday = Carbon::parse("This Sunday"); //you are able to retrieve this currently

$nextSunday = $sunday->addWeek();
```